# Enitiy Framework Query, Filtering child collections of child collections

Tags: entity-framework-4, filtering, eager-loading

I'm using eager loading to populate my object. Is it possible to filter child collections of child collections. The following code gives me the child collection of filtered periods. But I would also like to filter the child of periods where TradeStatus == TradeStatus.Open?

```
    public class Route
    {
       public Guid RouteId { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<Period> Periods { get; set; }
    }

    public class Period
    {
       public Guid PeriodId { get; set; }
       public virtual ICollection<Trade> Trades { get; set; }
       public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }

    public class Trade
    {
       public Guid PeriodId { get; set; }
       public string TradeName { get; set; }
       public decimal TradePrice { get; set; }
       public TradeStatus TradeStatus { get; set; }
    }

    string routeName = "UK_USA"

    Route route = Context.Set<Route>().SingleOrDefault(r => r.Name.Equals(routeName));

    if (route != null)
    {
        Context.Entry(route).Collection(r => r.Tenors).Query()
                      .Where(t => t.IsActive)
                      .Include(t => t.Trades).Load();
    }
```

I've tried the following but it returns

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property
>   defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation
>   properties and the Select operator for collection navigation
>   properties. Parameter name: path

```
Context.Entry(route).Collection(r => r.Tenors).Query()
                          .Where(t => ValidTenorName.Contains(t.Name))
                          .Include(t => 
                              t.Trades.Where(tr=> tr.TradeStatus ==  TradeStatus.Open).Load();
```

Is there a solution to this problem, or an alternative way using joins perhaps?

Thanks